# How to export CSV file from hive by using JAVA in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, linux, csv, hadoop

I am currently trying to export CSV file through Java by applying the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Octave {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s;
    Process p;
    try {
        String command = "hadoop fs -cat /user/hive/warehouse/new_cur2/* > /home/leo/new_cur2.csv";
        System.out.println(command);
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println("line: " + s);
        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println ("exit: " + p.exitValue());
        p.destroy();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    System.out.println("finish1");


}
}
```

But it won't export, I am trying to export by executing terminal command, does anyone know how to solve it please?
Also, trying this won't work either:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(string[]{"hadoop", "fs", "-cat", "/user/hive/warehouse/new_cur2/*", ">", "/home/leo/new_cur2.csv"});
```

Comment: Any Errors/Exceptions? Most probably it would not be able to locate 'hadoop' script. Also you should use hadoop-hdfs java APIs for this.

Comment: There is not Erros/Exceptions, noting is shown actually.

Comment: You need to read ErrorStream of process like you have read `p.getInputStream()`

Comment: Why are you trying this using JAVA? Can't this be done using a simple `hdfs dfs -get`? Also, Hadoop has a dedicated JAVA API for Read/Write operations.

Comment: Hive also has a JDBC driver, so if you really want to iterate on a series of records, you could do it on a standard `ResultSet`...